# crystal reports: suppress page footer and keep group footer when only one detail section exists

Tags: crystal-reports, conditional-statements, crystal-reports-2008

i'm fairly new to crystal reports, so i'm trying to include conditions for the first time. i am running a report that will often have two group groups for which i would like subtotals for dollars and percentages (group footer) and then total dollars (report footer). i am trying to accomplish two things:

1) when there is only one detail section, i would like to only show my subtotal values

2) also, in this scenario, i would like the text box to change to "total" rather than "subtotal"

i believe this can be accomplished through the "section expert", but i'm not familiar with the structure of formulas within crystal.

thanks in advance!

Comment: use a running field against an object then create a text formula against the object  for subtotal

Comment: Post your report structure

Answer (score 0):

This may help you for your first question

**1)** you need the report to calculate sum of your detail section (How many record display)
you can do this by using 'Running Total Field', available at your 'Field Explorer'
Choose 'SUM' to total up your detail section

2) Then, include your **1)** into a new formula. 
Your formula should have something like this

if **1)** =1 then subtotal